# Alternar classe no VueJS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, classes, toggle

Tenho 3 div com a classe ('option') e tenho uma classe como o nome de ('selected'). Gostaria de retirar a classe da div que já estiver com o ('selected') e mudar para a outra com o click.
tentei assim, mas ele não retira da ultima que ja esta com o ('selected')

```
<div @click="e => e.target.classList.toggle('selected')" class="col-4 option">
<div @click="e => e.target.classList.toggle('selected')" class="col-4 option">
<div @click="e => e.target.classList.toggle('selected')" class="col-4 option">
```

Comment: Chama uma função pra setar uma variável booleana. Ai tu faz uma verificação
Exp: :class="div ? 'col-4 option': 'col-4'"

Answer (score -3):

Usando bind você consegue definir a classe de forma condicional.

```html
<div :class="{'selected': foo == 'bar'}"></div>
```

Daria pra fazer algo como

```html
<div @click="foo = 'option-1'" :class="{'selected': foo == 'option-1' }"></div>
```